# Bind WPF ComboBox to XmlDataProvider in code

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, combobox

**Problem**
Unable to populate WPF ComboBox from XmlDataProvider in cs code behind.

**Background**
We have a WPF window as part of a much larger desktop WPF application. The window displays a ListView the data for which is obtained from an external xml file.

The objective is to be able to filter the ListView based on the selection made in a ComboBox.

The ListView is populated using an XmlDataProvider at Window_Loaded.

The ListView has four columns:

- Entry Date
- Project Name
- Node
- Entry

We need to be able to filter the list by Project Name.

The XML file needs to be external as it is up to the user which XML file they wish to view.

**WPF XAML Code:**

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="106*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="227*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="17*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="73*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="DAL File Location" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="DALLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="170,13,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="DALBrowse" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="235,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Click="DALBrowse_Click"/>
    <ListView x:Name="dal_list" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="6,6,6,6" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Entry Date" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=entry_date}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Project" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=project_name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Node" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=node_name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Entry" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=entry_text}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=sort_date}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Label Content="Project" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbProjects" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding  XPath=project_name}" DisplayMemberPath="@Name" SelectedValuePath="@Name"/>

</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    public partial class DALManager : Window
{
    public string dalFolder;
    public string dalFile;
    public DALManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DALLocation.Text = dalFolder;
        XmlDataProvider xmlData = new XmlDataProvider();
        xmlData.Source = new Uri(dalFolder + dalFile);
        xmlData.XPath = "DAL/entry";
        dal_list.DataContext = xmlData;
        cbProjects.DataContext = xmlData;

    }

    private void DALBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.DALLocation.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            string oldPath = CGlobals.dal_path + "\\DAL.xml";
            string newPath = fbd.SelectedPath + "\\DAL.xml";
            File.Move(oldPath, newPath);
            RegistryKey rgKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\SCP-Computers\\DocuMinder");
            CGlobals.dal_path = fbd.SelectedPath;
            using (RegistryKey
               rgInfo = rgKey.CreateSubKey("UserInfo"))
            {
                rgInfo.SetValue("dal_path", CGlobals.dal_path);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The XML File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DAL>
  <entry id="fe08125d-c785-40fc-816a-1e5ed3f06c7f-1">
    <sort_date>2017-10-01</sort_date>
    <entry_date>01/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test">DAL Test</project_name>
    <node_name>notes</node_name>
    <entry_text>here is line 1 changed</entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="fe08125d-c785-40fc-816a-1e5ed3f06c7f-2">
    <sort_date>2017-10-03</sort_date>
    <entry_date>03/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test">DAL Test</project_name>
    <node_name>notes</node_name>
    <entry_text>Here is line 2</entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="fe08125d-c785-40fc-816a-1e5ed3f06c7f-3">
    <sort_date>2017-10-10</sort_date>
    <entry_date>10/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test">DAL Test</project_name>
    <node_name>notes</node_name>
    <entry_text>Here is line 3 </entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="fe08125d-c785-40fc-816a-1e5ed3f06c7f-4">
    <sort_date>2017-10-11</sort_date>
    <entry_date>11/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test">DAL Test</project_name>
    <node_name>notes</node_name>
    <entry_text>Added line 4</entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="d9832a83-4aaa-4dd1-8c19-e469f1e5e1ed-1">
    <sort_date>2017-10-11</sort_date>
    <entry_date>11/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test">DAL Test</project_name>
    <node_name>Another Node With Notes</node_name>
    <entry_text>Here is a note in another node.</entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="b0e36598-26e1-4204-b11a-665da02ff121-1">
    <sort_date>2017-10-11</sort_date>
    <entry_date>11/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test 2">DAL Test 2</project_name>
    <node_name>Testing DAL in another project</node_name>
    <entry_text>This is another project.</entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="280743c7-c7e0-4345-9be3-fc502e3d1a45-1">
    <sort_date>2017-10-11</sort_date>
    <entry_date>11/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test 2">DAL Test 2</project_name>
    <node_name>Test new node</node_name>
    <entry_text>Test if node name gets include when new.</entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="5a660158-3d56-477f-935b-d8270560cd1d-1">
    <sort_date>2017-10-11</sort_date>
    <entry_date>11/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test 2">DAL Test 2</project_name>
    <node_name>Finding new node name</node_name>
    <entry_text>Add the note text. </entry_text>
  </entry>
  <entry id="414844c2-7498-4794-9267-1abcc99de3c3-1">
    <sort_date>2017-10-11</sort_date>
    <entry_date>11/10/2017</entry_date>
    <project_id>0</project_id>
    <project_name Name="Dal Test 2">DAL Test 2</project_name>
    <node_name>Test new new node</node_name>
    <entry_text>Here is the text</entry_text>
  </entry>
</DAL>
```

**The Result**

I am only getting the first of the project names listed in the ComboBox.

I have tried various combinations in the XAML file for binding the ComboBox based on numerous other questions on stackoverflow but am unable to find anything that works in my situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the XmlDataProvider's `XPath` only selects one block, so it should be `"DAL"`, the ComboBox binding's `XPath` should be `entry/project_name`, and the ListView binding's `XPath` should be `entry`. I'm not at a computer now, so can't confirm, but I remember getting bit by this not so straightforward XmlDataProvider behavior.

Comment: Thank you Szabolcs, that has done the trick. I'll supply the fixed code when I've managed to filter out the duplicates from the ComboBox.